# v4l2loopback installation. Not working on 5.14 kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, modprobe, v4l2loopback

Running the 5.14.1 kernel.

Tried using [this repo](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/59) to install v4l2loopback by compiling and installing(make; make install). It reported success.
As per [this recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/a/1339188/140265), installed the 5.14.1 headers

Tried to hence run

```
modprobe v4l2loopback
```

But it reported this output:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'v4l2loopback': Invalid argument
```

To be more particular, the verbose output specifies:

```
modprobe: INFO: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:365 kmod_set_log_fn() custom logging function 0x5609bbd73b90 registered
insmod /lib/modules/5.14.1-051401-generic/kernel/drivers/media/mc/mc.ko 
modprobe: INFO: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:892 kmod_module_insert_module() Failed to insert module '/lib/modules/5.14.1-051401-generic/kernel/drivers/media/mc/mc.ko': Invalid argument
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'v4l2loopback': Invalid argument
modprobe: INFO: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:332 kmod_unref() context 0x5609bd89f4e0 released
```

I have other kernels installed, the 5.4 and 5.13.0. I tried copying the mc.ko file from those files and running the modprobe command but it just gave a different error.

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'v4l2loopback': Exec format error
```

At this point, I feel like I've tried almost everything.

Answer (score 0):

Well,  I was upgrading to the next linux mint, having installed uxinvader-lts-mainline-focal and installed the latest headers, and it works after reboot. Woops.